# Rails: validation for top level domain only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I need some regex or maybe native Rails trick to check if user entered only domain (without "http", "https", "www" and so on.
So, this one would be valid:

> google.com.ua

And this would be invalid:

> https://www.google.com.ua

Maybe, it can be simplified just to check if string contains only dots and take it like valid one, and if it contains any other characters - block it.

Tell me please what is better to use for such case and what would be regex for it or another decision.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/5

Comment: URL's can contain `-` so probably better to use: `^(?!www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$`

Comment: yes, looks like what I need! Thanks. and thank to @Anthony for note about dash. 
Also Rails said to me: *"The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk..."*. Is it would be OK if I will use such one? /\A(?!www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\z/

Comment: @TiSer you can use `\A` instead of `^` and `\Z` instead of `$`.`-` included